# Data repeating on restarting App in Android Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-database

I am facing this problem whenever i run the app 1st time data in database remain single time but when i close the App and restart again data goes twice(means two same row in table).Similarly for 3rd, 4th time and so on. How do i get rid of this problem? I even put datas.clear in DataList.java but don't whether i have add the datas.clear() line in correct place or not. 
PLz help if there is any other problem in my code.

MainActivity.java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button listButton, addButton;
DatabaseHelper df;
private final static String TAG = "TestActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    df = new DatabaseHelper(this);

     addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
    uploadList();
}

public void uploadList(){
      DatabaseHelper df=new DatabaseHelper(this);
            df.open();
            try{
                InputStream im=getResources().getAssets().open("testdata.csv");
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(im));
                String data=br.readLine();
                while(data != null){
                    String t[]=data.split(",");
                    Product p=new Product();
                    p.setFirst(t[0]);
                    p.setSec(t[1]);
                    p.setThird(t[2]);
                    df.insert(p);
                    data=br.readLine();
                }
            }catch(Exception e){

            }

}
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java code

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final String FIRST="Name";
private static final String SECOND="Issn";
private static final String THIRD="ImpactFactor";

private static final String DATABASE="journal2016";
private static final String TABLENAME="journal";

private static final int VERSION=1;

SQLiteDatabase sd;

public void open(){
    sd=getWritableDatabase();
}
public void close(){
    sd.close();
}

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE, null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLENAME );
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLENAME + " ( NAME  TEXT, ISSN  TEXT, IMPACTFACTOR  REAL)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLENAME );
}



public long insert(Product p){
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(FIRST, p.getFirst());
    cv.put(SECOND, p.getSec());
    cv.put(THIRD, p.getThird());
    return sd.insertWithOnConflict(TABLENAME, null, cv,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);

}

public List<Product> getAllProduct(){
    ArrayList<Product> list=new ArrayList<Product>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLENAME, null);
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        Product p=new Product();
        p.setFirst(c.getString(0));
        p.setSec(c.getString(1));
        p.setThird(c.getString(2));
        list.add(p);
    }
    db.close();
    return list;
}
}
```

DataList.java code

```
public class DataList extends Activity{

List<Product> datas = new ArrayList<Product>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
    datas.clear();
    DatabaseHelper d=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    d.open();
    datas  = d.getAllProduct();
    ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datas));
}

}
```

Product.java

```
public class Product {
private String first;
private String second;
private String third;
public String getFirst() {
    return first;
}
public void setFirst(String first) {
    this.first = first;
}
public String getSec() {
    return second;
}
public void setSec(String sec) {
    this.second = sec;
}
public String getThird() {
    return third;
}
public void setThird(String third) {
    this.third = third;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return first + second + third;
}

}
```

Comment: You are calling `uploadList();` everytime your main activity starts. Without any control. So, what did you expect? It's working as you told it to.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from your `onCreate()` method:

```
df = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

as no need of it because you are create object of your `DatabaseHelper` class inside `uploadList()` method.
And also you are calling `uploadList()` method inside `onCreate()` thats why every time you launch the app, the `onCreate()` method executes and you `uploadList()` also execute. Try to put its calling statement in an onClickListener so it happens when you click a button or your choice of stuff.